# how to extract the request structure as xml string of each operation from WSDL file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have implemented a svc service serTest.svc which contains 3 operation:

opePing(PingRequest PingRequest)
opeTest(Test Test)
opeTest1(Test Test1)

From the serTest.svc service I have generated a WSDL file.

I have implemented a small console program where I use the C# ServiceDescription class to read some info from the WSDL file.

What I want now is a example of C# code of how to extract the request structure as xml string of each operation from the WSDL file like this e.g for opePing:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<opePing xmlns="http://test/webservices/">
<header>
<Aktoer xmlns="">
<Domaene>Test</Domaene>
<Bruger>Test</Bruger>
</Aktoer>
<InitSystem xmlns="">
<Noegle>7c4e35ca-4f60-4aee-a1a0-7763393dad07</Noegle>
<Proces>AliverTester</Proces>
<Applikation>1100</Applikation>
<Version>8.2.0.0</Version>
<Maskine>DEV</Maskine>
<Tidsstempel>2021-04-22T15:30:43.4875383+02:00</Tidsstempel>
<Kontekst>Test</Kontekst>
</InitSystem>
<Proces xmlns="">
<CPR>000000</CPR>
</Proces>
</header>
</opePing>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I another way like what SOAPUI are doing and showing the request xml structure.

It seems that I can't do this using the ServiceDescription class in C#.

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Consider including the C# code that you have done so far. That would help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this online tool: [https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com](https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/). It appears to be free and does a lot more than just generate XML for requests and response from WSDL.

There is also this: https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/wsdl_soap_analyzer.html, which can be downloaded, but not free.

And I hope this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-service-using-soap-request/) may help you alot.

Comment: Hi Krishna. I don’t want to use 3 parts tools or software.. I want to implement a c# program that can do the same, because i nede to use the code in another c# implementation!

Comment: Okey let me think something else